# Prove or disprove: if $n\mid x^2$ and $n<x$, then $n\mid x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove or disprove: if $n\mid x^2$ and $n<x$, then $n\mid x$.

I am having trouble finding a convincing proof. I have only examples that show it is true. Can someone please give me hints or solutions?

Comment: If $x<n$, then $n$ never divides $x$ (we are working with positive integers here).

Comment: sorry, I think itis n<x not x<n. Can I change the title

Comment: Yes, you can edit your post.

Comment: Note that $9\,|\,12^2$.

Comment: @lulu Ah ok found a counterexample. I think this question is answered now.

Comment: $4\mid 6^2$ but $4\nmid 6$ is a smaller counterexample (*smallest if you don't include negative numbers*)